# como abrir un archivo csv con python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

hola a todos tengo un codigo en python que me sirve para el envio de mensajes de texto , este codigo me lo paso el mismo fabricante del producto pero no entiendo mucho de python , me podrian decir como abrir el archi csv por favor aca les paso el codigo

```
from subprocess import *;
import json
import urllib
import csv
import sys


web_user = 'admin'

web_pass = 'admin'

lyric_ip = '192.168.1.202'

api_user = 'lyric_api'

api_pass = 'lyric_api'

api_version = '0.01'

url = "http://" + web_user + ":" + web_pass + "@" + lyric_ip + "/cgi-bin/exec"

class Mensaje:
    estado = -1
    contenido = ""
    destino = ""
    message_id = -1;
    def __init__(self, destino, contenido):
        self.estado = 0
        self.destino = destino
        self.contenido = contenido

def queue(self, url, api_user, api_pass, api_version):
    args = urllib.urlencode({'cmd': 'api_queue_sms', 'username': api_user, 'password': api_pass, 'content': self.contenido, 'destination': self.destino, 'api_version': api_version})
    print args
    res = urllib.urlopen(url + '?' + args).read()
    obj = json.loads(res)

    if obj['success']:
        mensajes[i].estado = 0
        self.message_id = obj['message_id']
        print 'Mensaje insertado exitosamente. Ticket: ' + str(obj['message_id'])
        return 1
    else:
        mensajes[i].estado = -1
        print 'Error al insertar mensaje. Codigo de error: ' + obj['error_code']
        return -1

def get_status(self, url, api_user, api_pass, api_version):
    if self.estado == -1 or self.estado >= 2:
        return self.estado

    args = urllib.urlencode({'cmd': 'api_get_status', 'message_id': self.message_id, 'username': api_user, 'password': api_pass, 'api_version': api_version})
    res = urllib.urlopen(url + '?' + args).read()
    obj = json.loads(res)

    if obj['success']:
        self.estado = obj['message_status']
        print 'Ticket: ' + str(self.message_id) + ' Estado: ' + str(self.estado)
        return obj['message_status']
    else:
        print 'Error al consultar estado. Codigo de error: ' + obj['error_code']
        return -1 

file = sys.argv[1]


csvfile = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=';')

mensajes = range(0)
i = 0
for row in csvfile:
    mensajes.append(Mensaje(row[0], row[1]))
    mensajes[i].queue(url, api_user, api_pass, api_version)
    i = i + 1

all_done = False
while not all_done:
    all_done = True
    for i in range(len(mensajes)):
        estado = mensajes[i].get_status(url, api_user, api_pass, api_version)
        if estado == 0 or estado == 1:
            all_done = False
            break
```

segun la documentacion para ejcutar el escript con el csv me dice esto

*Para ejecutar este script de prueba de la API Web:
     sms_test archivo.csv

*Donde archivo.csv es un archivo que contiene mensajes a enviar con el siguiente formato:

         num_destino1;contenido1

      num_destino2;contenido2*

pero no entiendo como tengo que ejecutarlo para que abra el archivo espero ayuda gracias

Comment: Modificaste el archivo? La 6a. línea `test_api_web.csv` se ve mal. La línea que abre el archivo es esta: `csvfile = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=';')`. Tal vez debes hacer en la sexta línea algo como esto: `file = test_api_web.csv`. Por favor __edita tu pregunta__ para agregar los mensajes de error.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta , eso yo le habia agregado para recorda el nombre del archivo csv que quiero abrir , sobre poner `file = test_api_web.csv` en el codigo dice  `file = sys.argv[1]` y en su cometario dice **Obtiene archivo CSV desde el primer argumento de la llamada a sms_test**

Comment: Así: __`python nombre_del_programa.py /ruta/del/archivo.csv`__.